# In VSCode, how can I make the left margin more visible?

Tags: visual-studio-code

It's really hard for me to see where the left gutter ends and the editor proper begins. That makes it difficult to see how much code is indented, but the truly infuriating thing is when I'm trying to get to the beginning of a line and hit backspace one too many times.

Is there any way to put a line at the edge of the gutter or make the gutter and the editor two different colors so that the edge of the editor is more obvious?